# Fetching string value from a particular tag in a file

Tags: awk

I have a large file which has messages that are separated by a `<>` tag.

I need to fetch the entire tag (with value). Please see example below:

```
<tvd:HostProductListStatus>000</tvd:HostProductListStatus><tvd:BeefProductListStatus>000</tvd:BeefProductListStatus><tvd:CustomerBranding>CC</tvd:CustomerBranding><tvd:InquiryAllowed>true</tvd:InquiryAllowed>
```

I need to just fetch and display **only** the following tag:value from the file, regardless if it appears more than once:

```
<tvd:BeefProductListStatus>000</tvd:BeefProductListStatus>
```

What would be command to do that?

Comment: Install `xmlstarlet`, it's a shell utility for parsing XML files.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want the input and output you posted, this could work,
using GNU grep, and with your file named `input`:

```
<input grep '<tvd:BeefProductListStatus>[^<]*</tvd:BeefProductListStatus>' -o -m1 \
| head -n1
```

`grep -o` asks to only print the part that matches, `[^<]*` prevents
matching more than one instance of `<tvd:BeefProductListStatus>` on
the same line, and `-m1` stops after the first matching lines. Since
having two instances of the tagged data on the same line would cause
grep to output each of them, `head -n1` is needed to prune this into
just the first match.

Answer (score -1):

1. change tag  to \n for work in multi-line mode
2. extract values in multi-line mode and hold values to hold space
3. given last line get back values from hold space to pattern space
4. substitude all values with tags and print results

---

```
sed -rn '
    s/<tvd:BeefProductListStatus>/\n/g;
    s/([^<]*).*/\1/Mg; H;               
    ${ g; s/\n+/ /g;
       s#\b(\w+)\b#<tvd:BeefProductListStatus>\1</tvd:BeefProductListStatus>\n#gp
     }
' file
<tvd:BeefProductListStatus>000</tvd:BeefProductListStatus>
<tvd:BeefProductListStatus>111</tvd:BeefProductListStatus>
<tvd:BeefProductListStatus>000</tvd:BeefProductListStatus>
```